# Android SurfaceView sharing and streaming for multi users drawing over the net

Tags: android, streaming, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-networking

I'm working on an application for sharing SurfaceView's draws with other android devices in real time (as a streaming). So all the connected devices on the net should be able to get the same canvas, draw in real time and see the modifications of each others.

I didn't found a way to do that. I thought about capturing screen shots and share them, but it will not allow multi-users modification.

How can I manage that? Is there an API or something like that? 
I couldn't find from where to start.